Adsorption energy value is too low
The adsorption energy I am finding is too low (-0.84 eV) compared to the published data (-2.57 eV). I followed the methodology from a published paper (number of layers, vacuum, slab placement, etc). The adsorbed molecule is the same, but the surface is slightly different - although I don`t think the difference should be this big.
Does anyone have a guess on what is the issue?
Thank you.
Here`s the input file:
&CONTROL
    calculation   = "relax"
    forc_conv_thr =  1.00000e-05
    max_seconds   =  1.49299e+10
    nstep         = 200
    pseudo_dir    = "/gpfs/home/s362484/pseudopot"
/
&SYSTEM
    a                         =  1.06742e+01
    c                         =  4.65880e+01
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
    ibrav                     = 4
    nat                       = 92
    nosym                     = .TRUE.
    nspin                     = 2
    ntyp                      = 5
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "gaussian"
    starting_magnetization(1) =  0.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(2) =  2.00000e-01
/

&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-05
    electron_maxstep = 1001
    mixing_beta      =  4.00000e-01
    startingpot      = "atomic"
    startingwfc      = "atomic+random"
/

&IONS
    ion_dynamics = "bfgs"
/

&CELL
    cell_dofree    = "xyz"
    cell_dynamics  = "bfgs"
    press_conv_thr =  5.00000e-01
/

K_POINTS {gamma}

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ru    101.07000  Ru.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Pt    195.07800  Pt.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
C      12.01070  C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
H       1.00794  H.pbe-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-nl-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Ru           -0.0448057059        3.0222786839        8.3063035242
Pt            3.8933622903        0.6891617127        8.4112558921
Pt            2.6131636020        3.0574430764        8.5576686056
Ru            1.2531974225        0.7828510011        8.2994547907
Ru            2.5318840169        1.5066486624        6.2028248008
Pt           -0.1202378435        1.4789991385        6.0794520349
Pt           -1.4378708223        3.7909137818        6.0848777210
Ru            1.2308518532        3.7597630424        6.2043838165
Ru            2.6685610000        4.6220820000        3.8373600000    0   0   0
Pt            1.3152790000        2.3364080000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Pt            0.0124680000        4.5929440000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Ru           -1.3028120000        2.3292090000        3.7859740000    0   0   0
Ru            0.0000000000        3.0813880000        1.6584900000    0   0   0
Pt            3.9838400000        0.7957140000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Pt            2.6810280000        3.0522500000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Ru            1.3657480000        0.7885150000        1.6071030000    0   0   0
Ru           -2.7475235490        7.6473244387        8.3177542084
Pt            1.1871528127        5.3558398082        8.4072034392
Pt           -0.1105600904        7.6569780607        8.4167921860
Ru           -1.4454163531        5.3834338836        8.3157771889
Ru           -0.1199813280        6.0997693854        6.1726290047
Pt           -2.7848940009        6.1013178044        6.1045166281
Pt           -4.1087127317        8.4204827845        6.0807074310
Ru           -1.4500175352        8.4081522718        6.1732978397
Ru            5.3371210000        0.0000000000        3.8373600000    0   0   0
Pt           -1.3532810000        6.9584900000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Pt           -2.6560930000        9.2150260000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Ru           -3.9713730000        6.9512920000        3.7859740000    0   0   0
Ru           -2.6685610000        7.7034710000        1.6584900000    0   0   0
Pt            1.3152790000        5.4177960000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Pt            0.0124680000        7.6743320000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Ru           -1.3028120000        5.4105980000        1.6071030000    0   0   0
Ru            5.3165058402        2.9168525002        8.6780196663
Pt            9.2453068196        0.7390259325        8.4165310714
Pt            7.9361175484        3.0409489961        8.4055185436
Ru            6.5982957609        0.7506209379        8.3289732443
Ru            7.8682074047        1.4792405088        6.1599867014
Pt            5.2175250061        1.4922905113        6.1025053312
Pt            3.9057473593        3.7988614211        6.1662943398
Ru            6.5613825897        3.8130840028        6.1213025912
Ru            8.0056390000        4.6220820000        3.8373600000    0   0   0
Pt            6.6524010000        2.3364080000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Pt            5.3495890000        4.5929440000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Ru            4.0343090000        2.3292090000        3.7859740000    0   0   0
Ru            5.3371210000        3.0813880000        1.6584900000    0   0   0
Pt            9.3209610000        0.7957140000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Pt            8.0181490000        3.0522500000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Ru            6.7028690000        0.7885150000        1.6071030000    0   0   0
Ru            2.5882942127        7.6858164557        8.3394819545
Pt            6.5372555892        5.3537023087        8.5709956529
Pt            5.2454608745        7.7044507544        8.4072092969
Ru            3.8158170142        5.4988179073        8.6946958988
Ru            5.2416311481        6.0954864615        6.1272412631
Pt            2.5633586702        6.0921120028        6.1151215810
Pt            1.2212664376        8.4110464345        6.1062613720
Ru            3.8796978314        8.3959201071        6.1628690348
Ru            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        3.8373600000    0   0   0
Pt            3.9838400000        6.9584900000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Pt            2.6810280000        9.2150260000        3.7961520000    0   0   0
Ru            1.3657480000        6.9512920000        3.7859740000    0   0   0
Ru            2.6685610000        7.7034710000        1.6584900000    0   0   0
Pt            6.6524010000        5.4177960000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Pt            5.3495890000        7.6743320000        1.6172820000    0   0   0
Ru            4.0343090000        5.4105980000        1.6071030000    0   0   0
C             3.2368178995        4.8519903506       10.7090259028
C             3.2563400443        3.3907078415       10.6575887059
C             4.5800990431        2.7682317381       10.7450084935
C             5.7801874622        3.5464348616       10.7290009429
C             5.7665393134        5.0142815689       10.6502601811
C             4.4377894020        5.6500071342       10.7822172907
H             6.5878189656        5.5320302120       11.1766341470
H             6.7164316793        3.0847778261       11.0839069685
H             4.6286116984        1.7379915180       11.1295026746
H             2.4319959056        2.8787000001       11.1882134396
H             2.3073405862        5.3261684333       11.0584977718
C             4.2759613486        6.9783446048       11.4436846581
O             5.4640906456        7.5483824169       11.8171646880
O             3.1874740887        7.5156121018       11.7143657477
H             5.2134918900        8.4203568769       12.2139055951
C             0.5088798115        5.8223605309       13.2772448806
C             0.0619902443        4.4939882207       13.3444136287
C             0.2505907876        3.7677706009       14.5265492215
C             0.8666689663        4.3536164741       15.6422334605
C             1.2700080130        5.6928796010       15.5771285251
C             1.0891831576        6.4284727845       14.4008270202
O             0.3178516340        6.4959189243       12.0891196148
H             1.4015075160        7.4807918235       14.3474556238
H             1.0179267262        3.7775371488       16.5663264404
H            -0.0814217834        2.7201173559       14.5825143890
H            -0.4151787551        4.0519098209       12.4570004642
H             1.7252962343        6.1894563348       16.4484814228
H             0.9700339406        7.2360429356       12.0238444160

